# How Do I Grab Text File Output and Pass Down Pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I've got an application that opens a winform and asks the user to input a PDF file. Because I can't read strings in PDF files easily, I need to convert it to a .txt. When the user clicks OK, the application does this.

The problem I'm having is now using the .txt file object and passing it to another command without knowing the name of it. When I try to pipe it to another command, it won't work because I don't have the path. I think this is because the output of conversion is the string "OK" and not the actual .txt file.

How can I convert the PDFs to text (I'm using [Xpdf](https://www.xpdfreader.com/)) and pass the converted file down the pipeline for further processing?

If the means I'm using is the problem, how can I accomplish this task another way?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$form.Controls.Add($button)
$button.Text = 'Get file'
$button.Location = '10,10'
$button.Add_Click({
    $ofd = New-Object system.windows.forms.Openfiledialog
    $ofd.Filter =  'PDFs (*.pdf)|*.pdf' 
    $script:filename = 'Not found'
    if ($ofd.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok') {
        $script:filename = $textbox.Text = $ofd.FileName
    }
})

$buttonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$form.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
$buttonOK.Text = 'Ok'
$buttonOK.Location = '10,40'
$buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'

$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)
$textbox.Location = '100,10'
$textbox.Width += 50

$form.ShowDialog()
$output = & "C:\Users\eakinsa\Desktop\Style Guide Report\Includes\bin32\pdftotext" $filename
$output |
    Get-Location -OutVariable textFile |
    Select-String -Path $textFile -Pattern ed
```

Per Ansgar:

I amended the lines last few lines to, for now, maintain the default functionality of pdftotext where it creates the file in the same directory with the same name, as with his suggestion, I could easily replace .pdf with .txt on the end of the file path, thereby having the flexibility to pass the correct file path to subsequent functions. That made it so I was able to search the text file.

```
& "C:\users\eakinsa\Desktop\Style Guide Report\Includes\bin32\pdftotext" $filename
$pdf = Get-Item $filename
$textfile = $filename -replace '\.pdf$', '.txt'
Select-String -Path $textfile -Pattern ed
```

Comment: First off in the script there u are not converting anything. All you did was make a winform with 2 buttons, a textbox and a Openfiledialog. The OK you are getting is the DialogResult that you set to OK, which a return saying the dialog is completed. Your textboxs value can be accessed from $textbox.Text. Place $textbox.Text after $form.ShowDialog() and you will see the file you selected. The $output you put doesnt mean anything

Comment: Nah it does legitimately create the text file. That function works, as it runs the function. But you're right the output variable clearly isn't doing anything. I hadn't thought to use textbox.text. That was dumb of me. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `pdftotext` with just the input PDF as argument it creates the output text file in the same directory with the same basename and the extension txt.

```
& pdftotext C:\temp\foo.pdf    # creates C:\temp\foo.txt
```

So you can build the text file path like this:

```
$pdf = Get-Item $filename
$textfile = Join-Path $pdf.DirectoryName ($pdf.BaseName + '.txt')
```

or like this:

```
$textfile = $filename -replace '\.pdf$', '.txt'
```

Alternatively you can tell `pdftotext` where to create the output file:

```
$textfile = 'C:\some\where\bar.txt'
& pdftotext $filename $textfile     # creates C:\some\where\bar.txt
```

Comment: This was an elegant solution that I wish I'd thought of. You're my hero. I appreciate it. I'm not terribly experienced with script writing as a whole, but far less with Powershell. Hadn't thought to pass arguments to pdftotext as I didn't even know it was possible. Though makes sense the way you did it, as they're not custom parameters of the function or anything. In any case, do you know of  any decent documentation anywhere for xpdf? I didn't find much when I initially searched.

Comment: @A.Eakins If you click [*Support*](https://www.xpdfreader.com/support.html) in the menu of the Xpdf homepage it'll take you to a list of the man pages for the commands. There's also the command help (`pdftotext --help`).